# Get headings of markdown formatted string

Tags: javascript, markdown

There is a markdown-formated string like

```
# Title 1
Lorem ipsum
## Subtitle

#Title 2
```

Now I need to extract just the (sub)titles from the complete text for creating an ul-list. So the result for this example should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Title 1
        <ul>
            <li>Subtitle</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title 2</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively I could use a simple text list like

```
1. Title 1
1.1. Subtitle
2. Title 2
```

So I began with this one:

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    if (lines[i][0] == '#')
        list.push(lines[i]);
}
```

But how can I recognize the level of the title in a correct way? And what is the best way to get a nested list of that?

Comment: You should use a data structure like a stack. You will need _pop_ the array, that is take something off whenever you see a bigger element. Your array should grow as you see nested tags and shrink when you see a tag bigger than the last. See http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1674-javascript-data-structures-stacks-queues-and-deques.html for more details.

Comment: The question is clearly not a duplicate, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35345549/866026) may be relevant.