# Markup regular expression help, double vs single symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

**Background**
I have burned myself out looking for this answer. The closest code I could find that works was from [Stack Edit](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit) specifically the [Markdown.Converter.js](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/82ba08fbfdc0c64036453d6fab24027565e5409c/public/res/libs/Markdown.Converter.js) script; copied below. This is a pretty heavy hitting regular expression though, my regex for finding ** for example happens in almost 1/5 of the steps and I don't need this much extra support.

```
function _DoItalicsAndBold(text) {
   // <strong> must go first:
   text = text.replace(/([\W_]|^)(\*\*|__)(?=\S)([^\r]*?\S[\*_]*)\2([\W_]|$)/g,"$1<strong>$3</strong>$4");
   text = text.replace(/([\W_]|^)(\*|_)(?=\S)([^\r\*_]*?\S)\2([\W_]|$)/g,"$1<em>$3</em>$4");
   return text;
}
```

**Question**
I'm trying to make my own very simple markdown script that makes these transformations:

* ---> Italics
** ---> Bold
__ ---> Underline

So far I can find all uses of ** (two stars, bold text) with this regex:

```
/(\*\*)(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/g
```

However I can not for the life of me figure out how to match only * (single star, italicized text) with one regular expression. If I decide to go further I may have to distinguish between _ and __ as well.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to properly write the regular expressions that will do this?

**Update / Clarifty of OP's Question**
I am aware of parser's and I am afraid that this question is going to be derailed from the point. I am not asking for parser help (but I do welcome and appreciate it) I am looking specifically for regular expression help. If this helps people get away from parser answers here is another example. Lets say I have an app that looks for strings inside double quotes and pulls them out to make tags or something. I want to avoid troll users trying to mess things up or sneak things by me so if they use double double quotes I should just ignore it and not bother making a tag out of it. Example:

> In this "sentence" my regex would match "sentence" and use other code I'm not showing you to pull out only the word: sentence.

Now if someone does double double quotes I just ignore it because no match was found. Meaning the inner word should not be found as a match in this instance.

> In this ""sentence"" I have two double quotes around the word sentence and it should be completely ignored now. I don't even care about ignoring the outer double quotes and matching on the inner ones. I want no match in this case.

Comment: regex is the wrong tool for the job. Write a parser, and maybe use regex for pieces *within* the parser, but don't expect regex to magically do everything.

Comment: see https://github.com/jgm/commonmark.js/blob/master/lib/inlines.js#L224 for a well-written italics/bold markdown parser...

Comment: @zzzzBov - Don't worry I am not expecting regex to do everything for me. I have my own parser that just needs a better regex. I'm not adding any parser info to this question because it is the regex that is needed.

Comment: @mb21 - Thank you for that link! This will be very good homework for me. I have updated my answer though to clarify that I really need regex help not parser help. My parser specific questions will come later.

Comment: Can there be escaped `*`s?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Yes I believe? Users can type \\* to preserve a * and not have it be changed but that is the next step.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wpm2kcz/2/). The idea is to match double asterisk first, then single asterisk items.With the help of optional groups and replace callback method logics it is possible to restrict matches to double or single asterisked items (mimicking negative lookbehind).

Comment: To understand why you keep getting references to parsers, see the first few paragraphs of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35345549/866026). It may be that only a parser will ever cover all edge cases completely.